# Scala - Most elegant way of initialising values inside array that's already been declared?

Tags: scala

I have a 3d array defined like so:

```
val 3dArray = new Array[Array[Array[Int]]](512, 8, 8)
```

In Javascript I would do the following to assign each element to 1:

```
for (i = 0; i < 512; i++)
 {
    3dArray[i] = [];
    for (j = 0; j < 8; j++)
    {
        3dArray[i][j] = [];
        for (k = 0; k < 8; k++)
        {
            3dArray[i][j][k] = 1;
        }
    }
}
```

What's the most elegant approach to doing the same?

Comment: For whatever it is worth, `3dArray` is not a valid identifier.

Comment: True, but it illustrates the point I hope.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Not sure there's a particularly elegant way to do it, but here's one way (I use suffix `s` to indicate dimension, i.e. `xss` is a two-dimensional array).

```
val xsss = Array.ofDim[Int](512, 8, 8)
for (xss <- xsss; xs <- xss; i <- 0 until 8) 
  xs(i) = 1
```

Or, using [transform](http://www.scala-lang.org/archives/downloads/distrib/files/nightly/docs/library/index.html#scala.collection.mutable.SeqLike) it gets even shorter:

```
for (xss <- xsss; xs <- xss)
  xs transform (_ => 1)
```

Comment: That 2nd way is what I thought I could do, but just didn't know how. Thanks!

Comment: With Scala 2.13.3, I get : `warning: method transform in trait SeqOps is deprecated (since 2.13.0).  Use 'mapInPlace' on an 'IndexedSeq' instead`. Replace `transform` with `mapInPlace` to avoid warning.

Answer (score 6):

```
for {
    i <- a.indices
    j <- a(i).indices
    k <- a(i)(j).indices
} a(i)(j)(k) = 1
```

or

```
for {
    e  <- a
    ee <- e
    i  <- ee.indices
} ee(i) = 1
```

Answer (score 2):

See: [http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Array$](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Array%24)

You have Array.fill to initialize an array of 1 to 5 dimension to some given value, and Array.tabulate to initialize an array of 1 to 5 dimension given the current indexes:

```
scala> Array.fill(2,1,1)(42)
res1: Array[Array[Array[Int]]] = Array(Array(Array(42)), Array(Array(42)))
enter code here

scala> Array.tabulate(3,2,1){ (x,y,z) => x+y+z }
res2: Array[Array[Array[Int]]] = Array(Array(Array(0), Array(1)), Array(Array(1), Array(2)), Array(Array(2), Array(3)))
```

Comment: You declare **new** arrays but original question was about "... initialising values inside array that's _already been_ declared?"